# get column of the parent table sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, json, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I have two models in SqlAlchemy which have a foreign key relation with each other. what i need is that when i get an object of `Post` as json it should also contain a few predefined columns of the `User` model as well.

Like in this case i need the name column of the `User` model to be returned to along eith the `Post` object.

i have tried to add a json property in the `Post` model but it returns only the model.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    message = db.Column(db.String(255))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    @property
    def json(self):
        return to_json(self, self.__class__)

def to_json(inst, cls):
    """
    Jsonify the sql alchemy query result.
    """
    convert = dict()
    # add your coversions for things like datetime's
    # and what-not that aren't serializable.
    d = dict()
    for c in cls.__table__.columns:
        v = getattr(inst, c.name)
        if c.type in convert.keys() and v is not None:
            try:
                d[c.name] = convert[c.type](v)
            except:
                d[c.name] = "Error:  Failed to covert using ", str(convert[c.type])
        elif v is None:
            d[c.name] = str()
        else:
            d[c.name] = v
    return json.dumps(d)
```

Comment: Can you show your code of `to_json`?

Comment: @stamaimer i have edited the post and added the function as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're querying for a `Post` model and would like a `User` and subset of the user info returned with it, but are only seeing the `Post.user_id`? In this case, I would use the `relationship` property that sqlalchemy provides:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one

Such that your Post class looks similar to

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    message = db.Column(db.String(255))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User, back_populates="user", uselist=False)
```

Comment: It must be a one to many relationship between user and posts.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include `uselist=False`, which clarifies that it is a one-to-one relationship :) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I said, In generally, the relationship between user and posts is one to many. One user might write many posts.

Comment: Oh wow, karma for me for skimming your reply! You're completely right @stamaimer . I'll update the link to `one-to-many`, but the relationship on `Post` is still correct I believe :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `relationship` from `SQLAlchemy` and modify your `to_json` to parse `relationship`.

```
class Post(db.Model):

    # other fields

    user = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=user_id)

    @property
    def json(self):

        attrs = self.__mapper__.attrs.keys()

        relationships = self.__mapper__.relationships.keys()

        fields = [item for item in [attr for attr in attrs if attr not in relationships]]

        container = {field: getattr(self, field) for field in fields}

        for relationship in relationships:

            related = getattr(self, relationship)

            if related:

                is_list = self.__mapper__.relationships[relationship].uselist

                if is_list:

                    container[relationship] = [record.to_dict(depth, include) for record in related]

                else:

                    container[relationship] = related.to_dict(depth, include)

        return container
```

I moved `to_json` to `json`. You'd better have a base model class which has a `to_json` method which all subclass inherited from the base model class can have this method. There're some other question might be raise in the process convert instance of data model class. The `to_json` method which i provide is a simplify version of [`to_dict`](https://github.com/stamaimer/ZhiFang/blob/master/app/models/__init__.py#L37).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a relationship in your Post model for users and write a query that performs a join using this relationship.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, attributes

class Post(Base):
    ...
    users = relationship("User")


Post.query().options(joinedload(Post.users).load_only('name')).all()
```

#### A better JSON conversion for your model instance.

You can define an abstract Model with a `to_dict` and `to_json` method that your models inherit from.

Also ensure that you're not forcing a load of deferred fields. See `__repr__`

```
def __repr__(self):
    fields = []
    for f in self.__table__.columns.keys():
        if f not in attributes.instance_state(self).unloaded:
            fields.append("%s=%s" % (f, getattr(self, f)))
        else:
            fields.append("%s=*" % (f,))

    return "<%s (%s)>" % ', '.join(self.__class__.__name__, fields)

def to_dict(self):
    dct = {}
    for field, value in self.__dict__.items():
        if not field.startswith('_'):
            if isinstance(value, Base):
                dct[field] = value.to_dict()
            else:
                dct[field] = value

    return dct


def to_json(self):
     return json.dumps(
               self.to_dict())
```